# Redirect any directory if it has a specific query string

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect all pages with a specific query string to another page.
So many pages have this query string, but the URI's are different.
I want to capture any URI and if it has this query string to redirect it but nothing I am doing is working.

So just to be clear:
http://example.com/?redirectme=1
would redirect to
 
http://example.com/newpage
while also:
http://example.com/randompage/rtandomsirectory?redirectme=1
would also redirect to
http://example.com/newpage

I am sure there must be 2-3 lines I can put in the htaccess to do this but it is not working.
This is a wordpress site if that should make a difference.

Here is what I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^redirectme=1$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^redirectme=1$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

different variations:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^redirectme=1$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

and for the first line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
```

And so on....

Any experts on this here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule as **top rule** in your site root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^redirectme=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /newpage? [R=301,L]

# remaining rules below this line
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I realize now that it was also the positioning!